# How can I upload a build to the App Store from a project built with VSCode?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code, app-store

I've built an app for iOS using VSCode, and I'm trying to submit it to the app store but I can't seem to use XCode to open it, or bundle it in a way that Transporter will accept.  What am I missing?

Thank you!

I tried opening the project with XCode.